# Discord.js how to check if user has a role on a specific server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to check if the user has a role on a specific server regardless on which server they use the bot.

For example, if I have 2 servers, server A and server B, I want to check if the user has the role "Beginner" on server A, even if I use the command in server B.

I couldn't find a way to do this on the internet, `message.member.roles` seems to only return the roles of the server the command was written in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
function hasRole(guildId, roleId) {
    // Get second guild
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);

    // Get member in that guild, by ID
    const member = guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id);

    // If member is in that guild,
    if (member) {
        // return whether they have this role
        return member.roles.cache.has(roleId);
    }
}
```

Of course the bot has to be in both servers.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to find the server then find the member from inside the server.
To find the guild you will use the [`guild.fetch(...)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetch) method and from there you then use the [`guildMember.fetch(...)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=fetch) function to find the member.

Example:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", function(message) {
    // Find the guild
    let guild = client.guilds.fetch("guild-id");
    // Find the member in the guild
    let member = guild.members.fetch(message.author.id);

    if (member)
        message.reply("You are in the server " + guild.name);
});
```

Comment: `Guild#fetch()` requires a `Guild` instance, and there is no need to fetch when you can get from cache. Additionally, you would have to await the fetches for them to work properly